# Two same GPUs, but different performances in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

I'm using two same GPUs, Geforce RTX 2080 ti, in ubuntu 16.04 for deep learning.

Since a week ago, suddenly, I've been in trouble with a GPU.

One gpu has worked very well, but another one has shown errors.

The error is "An illegal memory access was encountered".

I searched for solving this problem and 
I updated CUDA version to 10.2, nvidia driver version to 440.64.00.
I modified /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "Interactive" "0"  # I added this**
EndSection
```

Now it seems to work well, but randomly.
Almost, it shows cuda runtime error(700) gpu memory access error.

When it worked well, I found different performances between them.

A normal gpu showed below.

```
avg_loss 0.04434689141832936
max_acc 0.9197530864197536
avg_acc 0.6771604938271607
```

Another one, an abnormal gpu, showed below.

```
avg_loss 0.16801862874683451
max_acc 0.9197530864197536
avg_acc 0.541358024691358
```

I typed same commands Like

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={gpu_num} python main.py --test config/www.yml
```

I also tried other open source codes but same situation.

Maybe the abnormal gpu has been broken, but I don't know.

So, does anyone have solutions to fix the gpu (an illegal memory access)?

I think, it's not driver compatibility issue, codes, or some mistakes because the problem occurred for only the abnormal gpu.